# How to use a loop to read an unknown file size?

Tags: c++

So I have this problem.

> "write a complete program to read the data in file called "ingolf.txt" when the data looks like this:
>
> 78  78  Smith Joe
> 67  69  Morris Mark
> 65  88  Kimball Craig
> ...
> 73  75  Dennison David

where the 3 dots indicate more lines of data"

This is the loop that I'm using to read the file.

```
string line;

while(getline(dataFile, line)) {
   dataFile >> round1;
   dataFile >> round2;
   dataFile >> firstName;
   dataFile >> lastName;
   cout << round1 << " ";
   cout << round2 << " ";
   cout << firstName << " ";
   cout << lastName << " ";
}
```

When I use this loop, it repeats the last file line twice.  Am I doing something wrong?
I used eof() before this and it worked but I read that it's bad practice so I found this loop to use instead.  I'm also not sure why I need a variable for this.  The file is an unknown size.  I'm a beginner so please explain in noob friendly way :D

Comment: Use `fscanf` function instead

Comment: `while(getline(dataFile, line)` looks OK so far, can you please give a more complete [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @MaciejBaranowski Why that?? What makes `fscanf()` superior to `getline()`, explain in detail please!

Comment: After using getline you still need to split the line to get actual data. fscanf is convenient here, because format of every line is the same, so we may easily extract these lines to actual data structures

Comment: You need to post more code. The *one* line you posted works (when you fix the missing paren).

Comment: I added the body of the loop, could it have something to do with that?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/K7EkBx)

Comment: You do realize that the above code will read one line of text, then another line of `round1`, `round2`, etc - did you mean to create a `stringstream` from `line` and extract data from that?

Comment: @MaciejBaranowski _"fscanf is convenient here"_ No, `std::istringstream` is the more convenient and consistent choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should have is

```
string line;

while(getline(dataFile, line)) {
    istringstream is(line);

    is >> round1;
    is >> round2;
    is >> firstName;
    is >> lastName;

    // ...
}
```

---

In your sample `getline()` already consumes a line from the input stream, you're stepping into the loop body, and again consume

```
dataFile >> round1;
dataFile >> round2;
dataFile >> firstName;
dataFile >> lastName;
```

from the input stream (the next line actually). So you're alternatingly *throw away/missing a* line of input.

Answer (score 1):

You should either read a line and then parse out the individual fields or read directly into your variables. πάντα ῥεῖ posted an answer showing the first option and here is the second:

```
while (dataFile >> round1 >> round2 >> firstName >> lastName) {
    cout << round1 << " ";
    cout << round2 << " ";
    cout << firstName << " ";
    cout << lastName << " ";

    // ...
}
```

Note that this will work because each field is space-delimited. You'll need a different method if a field can contain whitespace.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I like your answer for addressing the problem in the posted code, this is just an alternative solution.

Comment: Alternative solutions are appreciated of course, that's why I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: We're upvoting buddies. Cheers!

Comment: Slaìnte! I'm goin' to have a nip from the water of life now, reminding you ;-) ...